# If $f(n) = (n+1)^n$ and $g(n) = n^{n+1}$, show that $f = o(g)$

Tags: combinatorics

From what I understand from this question, it relates to the concept of the Little-O Notation where $f = o(g)$ or $f(n) = o(g(n))$ relates to $f(n)/g(n)$ and tends to reach $0$ as $n$ tends to increase to infinity.

For questions like $f(n) = 30n^2$ and $g(n) = n^3$, the answer can be reduced to $30/n$ and as $n$ approaches infinity, the ratio eventually reaches $0$.

How would this concept apply to the question stated in the title?

Comment: It's the same idea: $f(n) /g(n) =\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) ^n\cdot\frac 1n<\frac 3n$

Comment: @Jochen how would the equation (1+1/n)^n = e play a role in this question and how could we apply it? 
e is known as the Euler's number where it follows the concept above where we approach zero. However, how would we represent it and apply it within this question? By the way, thank you for the explanation so far, it gave an easier way of understanding the problem.

Comment: Be careful, there is no integer $n$ with $(1+1/n) ^n=e$, but we have $(1+1/n) ^n<e<3$ for all positive integers $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question on Jochen's comment:

Use the exponential form and the asymptotic approach $\ln(1+x) \underset{x \to 0}{\sim}x$.

$\begin{align*}
\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n^{n+1}}&=\frac{e^{n \ln(n+1)}}
{e^{(n+1) \ln(n)}}\\
&=e^{n \ln \big(n(1+ \frac{1}{n}) \big)-(n+1) \ln(n)}\\
&=e^{n \ln(n)+n \ln(1+ \frac{1}{n})-n \ln(n)- \ln{n}}\\
&=e^{n \ln(1+ \frac{1}{n})- \ln(n)}\\ 
&\underset{+ \infty}{\sim}e^{n \cdot \frac{1}{n}- \ln(n)}\\
&=e^{1- \ln(n)}\\
 &\underset{n \to + \infty}{\longrightarrow}0
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e}{n}=0$$